# ngspice result display via php

Tags: php, pspice

I am trying to display ngspice output via PHP.

I am able to display the terminal output but i am unable to display the graph. I get an error saying:

> "ERROR: (internal)  This operation is not defined for display type
>   printf. Can't open viewport for graphics. Note: No ".plot", ".print",
>   or ".fourier" lines; no simulations run "

THis is my netlist file:

```
*ngspice netlist* 

v1 1 0 dc 5v

r1 1 0 1k

.tran 1e-03 11e-03 1e-03

.control 

run 

plot allv 

.endc 

.end
```

When this executed separately on terminals gives graph but I am unable to display graph via PHP. I run this code in HP by this code:

$output=shell_exec(' ngspice /var/www/html/eSIM/netlist.txt 2>&1 ' );

Answer (score 0):

ngspice seems to not have a connection to an output display and/or X-server.

Is there any error/warning message just after starting ngspice?

There is a lot of comments at http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php about what might happen when you start a program by shell_exec (e.g. missing PATH entries ...).